# how to disable TOAD parallel slave processes in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, toad

I have a 12.5 TOAD going against multiple Oracle SIDs. On one of them the first connection opens a session with 4 instant parallel slave processes (which show up as additional sessions in v$session, freaking out the local DBA). And then each next SQL editor adds another 5.

On other SIDs this is not happening.

Is there a known way to disable this in TOAD? (so far nothing worked)

EDIT #1: Okay, this turned out not to be related to TOAD. Every session opened against that instance (just a blank conn too) automatically creates 4 additional slave processes right away, which are only seen within gv$session for your own connection (which is why it looked like other TOAD connections were not having it).
I will keep this thread open for some time until I find out what the deal is with the worker processes.

FINAL EDIT:  Finally found out that they force multiple threads for each statement on the instance level, so this has nothing to do with TOAD or clients.

Comment: Go to session browser in Toad and see what each of those sessions are doing. Maybe it is because of an "option" that can be disabled. I'd say to check with Toad support in case that is a bug.

Comment: Looks like they were all running various TOAD queries, 3 against gv$session, one empty - no open cursors, main session - selected from gv$open_cursors - so all these are app calls.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't "real" parallelism.  Oracle uses small parallel queries for GV$ dynamic performance views on a Real Application Cluster (RAC).  Oracle is currently a shared-everything architecture where all the data resides on every node.  Except for dynamic performance views, since most activity only happens on a specific node and is tracked on that node.

This behavior will only occur on some SIDs because GV$ only uses parallel queries if the database is clustered.  The queries may consume parallel processes, but only one per node and these queries usually do not use up much resources.

These queries should not normally be a problem.  I can think of a few scenarios where they would look like a problem, but would not be the root problem:

1. **PARALLEL_MAX_SERVERS too low.**  Parallel sessions should not be a scarce resource.  A DBA is right to worry about run-away parallelism.  But when organizations worry about such
   a small number of parallel sessions it's usually because they've created an artificial scarcity by shrinking PARALLEL_MAX_SERVERS.  The default value for
   [parallel_max_servers](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-B6CE9EA3-B846-4AA7-B668-FD3BEE433A24.htm#REFRN10158) is usually "PARALLEL_THREADS_PER_CPU * CPU_COUNT * concurrent_parallel_users * 5".
   If your server was purchased in this century there's no need to worry about a few extra sessions.
2. **Bad interconnect** RAC needs a really good network connection between nodes.  100Mbps Ethernet is not going to cut it and the nodes will spend a lot of time communicating.
3. **Bad dictionary or fixed object statistics.**  Data dictionary queries may be slow if dictionary or fixed object stats have never been gathered.  If these queries are running for a long time, try gathering stats with: `exec dbms_stats.gather_dictionary_stats;` and `exec dbms_stats.gather_fixed_object_stats;`.

Below is a demonstration of GV$ using parallel queries.  This will only work on a RAC database.

```
> explain plan for select * from v$process;

Explained.

> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => 'basic'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4113158240

------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name    |
------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |         |
|   1 |  FIXED TABLE FULL| X$KSUPR |
------------------------------------

8 rows selected.

> explain plan for select * from gv$process;

Explained.

> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => 'basic'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3900509504

-------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name       |
-------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)| :TQ10000   |
|   3 |    VIEW              | GV$PROCESS |
|   4 |     FIXED TABLE FULL | X$KSUPR    |
-------------------------------------------

11 rows selected.

>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your explanation. I finally found out that they force multiple threads for each statement. So this is actually set on the instance level, not in TOAD or clients.

Comment: @Access_granted What do you mean by "force multiple threads"?

Comment: I believe the parameter used was parallel_degree_policy set to AUTO, which, on 4 instances they have for that SID, throws 4 slaves, if I understand this correctly

Comment: @access_granted That still raises some questions.  Setting that parameter to AUTO still shouldn't normally cause multiple parallel threads per instance.  Oracle should be able to detect that querying GV$SESSION is under the threshold of a query that qualifies for parallelism.  See the description in [the parameter reference page](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-BF09265F-8545-40D4-BD29-E58D5F02B0E5.htm#REFRN10310), and also check out the link at the bottom for the VLDB Guide.  Maybe another parameter is configured wrong, system statistics are off, fixed stats are off, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To minimize the number of sessions set the following options on the Oracle|Transaction page in Options.

1. Disable "Execute queries in threads"
2. Enable "Execute scripts in Toad session"
3. Set "Session for Explain Plan" to "Main Toad Session"

Comment: Disabled / Enabled / Set to Main Toad Session => same behavior, and only for one SID, other SIDs use a single session, no slaves.

Comment: And even weirder - TOAD sessions from other users don't exhibit this. Just from mine, and only on one SID.

Comment: I'm not sure what else would cause this. I'll ask around.

Comment: A comment from someone in the know who doesn't use StackOverflow. "If there are tables defined with parallelism and he goes to Schema Browser-Tables-Data on them, then Oracle will do just as the table definition tells it - to query the table with parallel slaves." There's an option to disable parallelism in the Schema Browser and Master Detail Browser. In the Editor if you're selecting from such a table you'll need to include the NOPARALLEL hint manually. Does any of this sound like it could be it?